Unable to make a successful ping via ethernet cable
I have connected my Dell laptop to another laptop via an Ethernet cable and had set the DHCP, where it is not connecting. So, I set a manual IP, and both devices were connected, I even checked with ethtool; the link was detected. My device (PC2 - 192.168.1.49) has an issue with pinging. I had even tried disabling the firewall, flushing out the IP tables, changing the Ethernet cable, etc. When I used to analyze the packets in Wireshark, I was able to see the device was not receiving the ICMP reply. When I checked the ARP table (arp -a), the device PC2 is not able to have the MAC address of PC1, but PC1 has the PC2's MAC. There is no issue with PC1, and something stops PC2 from getting the reply from PC1. Any suggestions in sorting out this issue would be very helpful!
PC 1 with IP 192.168.1.11:
pc1--QA--POY:/home# arp -a
? (172.21.243.82) at 78:f2:35:42:70:07 [ether] on wlp43s0
? (192.168.1.49) at c8:4b:d6:3c:a1:f5 [ether] on enp44s0
? (172.21.247.149) at 3c:55:76:89:15:2d [ether] on wlp43s0
? (172.21.243.54) at 34:9f:7b:d6:ef:3b [ether] on wlp43s0
_gateway (172.21.240.1) at 00:09:0f:09:00:1a [ether] on wlp43s0

PC2 with IP 192.168.1.49 (This is my other device):
pc2--QA--POY:/home/# arp -a
? (192.168.1.11) at <incomplete> on enp45s0
_gateway (172.21.240.1) at 00:09:0f:09:00:1a [ether] on wlp44s0
? (172.21.243.82) at 78:f2:35:42:70:07 [ether] on wlp44s0
? (172.21.243.54) at 34:9f:7b:d6:ef:3b [ether] on wlp44s0

I feel like it can send the request but is unable to receive the reply am I correct? , if so how can I fix this?

Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Edit your question and add the information.

PC2 couldn't resolve IP of PC1, can you edit your post with result of   ip a s dev enp44s0 for PC1 and enp45s0 for PC2 ?

You probably need to see if the data units can be routed ... Check ip route on both PCs and add needed routes if they don't exist or fix them if they direct traffic through the wrong interface/link.

Actually, the issue was when the 1G cable was connected, both devices showed the Ethernet connection as connected but were not pinging.
So the initial steps to be taken first are:

ethtool (interface name) - to confirm the link was detected.
Both devices need to be in the same subnet.
ip addr show - to check if it has an IP.
ip route - should have that respective subnet.
arp -a - It should reflect the IP with its MAC address. Check on both devices, but only after pinging will it reflect in arp -a (ARP cache).

In my case, the above steps were perfect except for the 5th one, so the next steps I took were:

tcpdump the ping packets and check the reason.
From the above, I came to know that my device is not sending the ARP reply for the other device's ARP request.
So in this, I checked for OVS with sudo ovs-vsctl show. In that, I saw the Ethernet interface was inside the OVS bridge, which was the reason for the failure. After that, I removed the interface from that using sudo ovs-vsctl del-port ovsbr(bridge name) enp45s0(interface name) and it worked perfectly. Similarly, if someone is facing this issue, then your Ethernet interface must be embedded somewhere else, so you need to check and remove that, then the ping will be successful.

